# Trying to do a basic online shop code with python

Tags: python

i'm a foundation year student at University so I am very new to coding. I'm struggling with this and am in need of some help, this is the question and code I have currently written:

"Write a python program to simulate an online store.
The program should begin by displaying a list of products and their prices. There should be a minimum of 4 products offered. The program should ask the user to choose a product and then ask the user to enter the quantity they require of that product. The program should then allow the user to keep choosing more products and quantities until they enter something to indicate they want to end the program (e.g. a given number or ‘q’ or ‘exit’). The program should then tell the user the total amount for the products they have selected. "

```py
        shopping_basket = {}
        print("Welcome to the online drink store!\nThese are the drinks we offer\n1. Lemonade: £1.50\n2. 
        Coke: £2.00\n3. Fanta £1.00\n4. Water: £0.50")

        Price = {"Lemonade": 1.50, "Coke": 2.00, "Fanta": 1.00, "Water": 0.50 }

        option = int(input("Which drink would you like to purchase?: "))

        while option!= 0:
            if option == 1:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 1.50
            print("The price is: " + str(total))
        elif option == 2:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 2.00
            print("The price is: " + str(total))
        elif option == 3:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 1.00
            print("The price is: " + str(total))
        elif option == 4:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 0.50
            print("The price is: " + str(total))

            print("Would you like another item? enter Yes or No:")
        else:
            print("The total price of your basket is: " , total = Price * qnty)
```

This is the code I have tried, but after it stating the price it just constantly asks for the quantity.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Is your code indented as in your script? It seems odd to me. Please check it and edit the question to properly indent it.

Comment: `after it stating the price it just constantly asks for the quantity` - because your "would you like another item" is just a text, not an input + your "which drink would you like" is outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to post a new answer but instead make a comment, but alas, not enough reputation.

I just wanted to add to [Daemon Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125110/daemon-painter)'s answer and say that the final total bill also isn't working as it is multiplying a dict by an int.

What could work is to initialize out of the loop the total variable as well a new total_cost variable, and place:

```
total_cost += total
```

Inside the while loop but outside the if conditions. 
That way the last line can just be:

```
print("The total price of your basket is: ", total_cost)
```

Edit: the code, working as intended:

```
    price = {"Lemonade": 1.50, "Coke": 2.00, "Fanta": 1.00, "Water": 0.50}
    shopping_basket = {}

    print("Welcome to the online drink store!\nThese are the drinks we offer\n1. Lemonade: £1.50\n2. Coke: £2.00\n3. Fanta £1.00\n4. Water: £0.50")

    buy_another_flag = 1
    total_cost, total = 0, 0

    while buy_another_flag != 0:
        option = int(input("Which drink would you like to purchase?: "))

        if option == 1:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 1.50
            print("The price is: " + str(total))
        elif option == 2:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 2.00
            print("The price is: " + str(total))
        elif option == 3:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 1.00
            print("The price is: " + str(total))
        elif option == 4:
            qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
            total = qnty * 0.50
            print("The price is: " + str(total))

        total_cost += total

        buy_another_flag = int(input("Would you like another item? enter Yes (1) or No (0):"))
    print("The total price of your basket is: ", total_cost)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys, is someone able to modify it and post it for me? I'm able to understand it more if I can look at it fully!

Comment: I've edited my comment.

Comment: Awesomet thanks! I still can't get the total cost to come up or the "would you like another item to work :("

EDIT: Sorry I did it wrong, but thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Did you notice what I change in my answer in the last two lines, compared to yours?
I placed the buy_another_flag input outside the if's but inside the while loop, and the last print with the total cost is now completely out of the while loop.


Edit: No problem, glad I could help. Don't forget to choose an answer if you feel my or any other answer, answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping indefinitely in the while loop.

Once you assigned option via User input here:

```
option = int(input("Which drink would you like to purchase?: "))
```

this condition is always fulfilled:

```
while option!= 0:
```

Here, you should not just print, but re-assign the option:

```
print("Would you like another item? enter Yes or No:")
```

something like this:

```
option = int(input("Would you like another item? enter Yes or No:"))
```

I hope this is pointing you in the right direction :)

(I've made assumptions on how you should have the code formatted in your original script. They might be wrong...)